# Pandas split column if condition, else null

Tags: python, pandas

I want to split a column. If it has a letter (any letter) at the end, this will be the value for the second column. Otherwise, the second column should be null

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({"data": ["0.00I", "0.01E", "99.99", "0.14F"]})
```

desired result:

```
    a    b
0 0.00   I
1 0.01   E
2 99.99  None
3 0.14   F
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) with the `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(\D)?` regex:

```
out = data['data'].str.extract(r'(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(\D)?').set_axis(['a', 'b'], axis=1)
```

Or, if you want to remove the original 'data' column while adding new columns in place:

```
data[['a', 'b']] = data.pop('data').str.extract('(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(\D)?')
```

output:

```
       a    b
0   0.00    I
1   0.01    E
2  99.99  NaN
3   0.14    F
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ZRjKQu/1)

```
(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)  # capture a number (with optional decimal)
(\D)?            # optionally capture a non-digit
```

Comment: thank you, i was so close, had tried extract with no luck. RegEx is just a mystery, glad some folk speak it enough to answer these questions

Answer (score 0):

try using a regular expression and apply

```
def find_numeric(x):
    if re.search("[[0-9]+\.[0-9]+", x):
        return re.search("[0-9]+\.[0-9]+", x).group()
    else:
        return ""

def find_alpha(x):
    if re.search("[a-zA-Z]+", x):
        return re.search("[a-zA-Z]+", x).group()
    else:
        return "None"
    
data = pd.DataFrame({"data": ["0.00I", "0.01E", "99.99", "0.14F"]})    

data["numeric"] = data["data"].apply(find_numeric)

data["alpha"]= data["data"].apply(find_alpha)

print(data)
```

output:

```
data numeric alpha
0  0.00I    0.00     I
1  0.01E    0.01     E
2  99.99   99.99  None
3  0.14F    0.14     F
```

​